# Unable to connect to sql server 2008 with django 1.4 app using pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, django, ubuntu

we are unable to connect with the following error when we try using the django shell;

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Our database settings file looks like this;

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sql_server.pyodbc'                   #  'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
#DATABASE_ODBC_DSN = 'websiteredesign'
#DATABASE_ODBC_DRIVER = 'FreeTDS'
DATABASE_NAME = db             # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = db             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'dcls'         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = '10.64.4.135'  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = '1433'
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
    'driver': 'FreeTDS',
    'dsn': 'dcls',
    'host_is_server': True,
    'extra_params': 'TDS_VERSION=8.0'
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': DATABASE_ENGINE,
        'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DATABASE_HOST,
        'PORT': DATABASE_PORT,
        'OPTIONS': DATABASE_OPTIONS,
    },
    'dcls': {
        'ENGINE': DATABASE_ENGINE,
        'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': DATABASE_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DATABASE_HOST,
        'PORT': DATABASE_PORT,
        'OPTIONS': DATABASE_OPTIONS,
    }
}
```

You can ignore some of the duplication.  that was just some tests we did.  Nothing seems to help.  We ported over from a working django 1.3 system that is working.  any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a number of DB changes in 1.4 (timezones and bulk inserts to start) which required changes in the third-party backends. However it looks like [`django-pyodbc`](http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/) has not seen a commit in over a year. As of this writing the last commit was in June 2011. This most likely means that `django-pyodbc` is not compatible with 1.4.

Comment: We kind of came to the same conclusion when we saw that some variables were depricated by django in 1.3 and completely removed in 1.4, but the django-pyodbc still requires them. We are going to try to mysql db instead.

Comment: If you are running the webserver on windows you can look into django-mssql http://django-mssql.readthedocs.org/ which does support 1.4.